# How to find pcf file on mac?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion, osx-leopard, osx-server

I am looking for .pcf file in my mac. I searched for many forum that I can find the VPN Settings connection from a pcf file. I searched in multiple location but I could not find anywhere.
Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: See this SU question: [Location of Cisco VPN client profile configuration file (.pcf file) on Mac OS X](http://superuser.com/questions/239246/location-of-cisco-vpn-client-profile-configuration-file-pcf-file-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to use Spotlight?

Command-F
Set criteria to: "Name matches pcf" and "System Files are included"

D

Comment: In Mac, its no way to find pcf file.